# Laravel blade parent section problems

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have little problem with laravel blade.

In parent view I have

```
@section('sidebar')
  @include('sidebar.widget')
  @include('sidebar.widget2')
@show
```

and in few views I needed to rewrite sidebar section so I did this

```
@section('sidebar')
  @include('sidebar.widget3')
@stop
```

But there is a problem. In views where I rewrite parent sidebar it still loads parent sidebar widget queries and inner sections like in one widget I have

```
@section('w-scripts')
<script>
// Js code
</script>
@stop
```

and Even this widget isn't loaded in some pages it still loads that `w-scripts` section and sql queries related to widget.

Anyone know how can I fix this? I really need parent sidebar so I don't need to copy/paste same code in nearly all views and I need different sidebar content in few views.

Comment: I tried @section('sidebar') content @overwrite too, result is same.

Comment: which laravel version you use? I think in 5.1 and above you use `@endsection` and not `@stop`.

Comment: you can try stacks in blade https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#stacks

Comment: @J.Eggerstedt 5.2 and both `@endsection` and `@stop` works

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
@section('sidebar')
  @parent
  @include('sidebar.widget3')
@stop
```

Comment: I don't need to load parent sidebar widgets but stop load widget related queries or inner sections if that widget isnt loaded when I rewrite sidebar section